# A multivariable complex analysis problem probably related with Baire Category Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, baire-category

The original problem is an extension of the Hurwitz theorem into the case of multivariables, which states that given a region $D\in \mathbb{C}^n$, if the sequence of analytical functions $f_k(z),z\in D$ converges uniformly to some $f$ on any compact subset $E$ of $D$, and all $f_k(z)$ doesn't assume value $0$ on $D$, prove that $f$ should whether be constant $0$ or also doesn't assume $0$ on $D$.

By the Weierstrass Theorem in the multivariable case, $f(z)$ is still analytical on $D$. However, the Uniqueness Theorem is a little diffrent from the single variable case. In single variable case we know that the inverse image of $0$ for a nonzero analytical function can't have an accumulation point in the analytical region, but the multivariable case relents it to "$f^{-1}(0)$ can't have interior point", which makes this harder to tackle than the Hurwitz Theorem in the single variable case.

I tried several methods like the maximum modulus and can't figure it out. Now I am trying another one: First of all, $f$ is analytical on $D$. If it's constant zero function, we don't need to prove anything, and if not, by the Uniqueness Theorem $f^{-1}(0)$ has no interior point (and by continuity it is closed thus nowhere dense). If we set $E_{k,n}=\{z\in D\vert |f_k(z)|<\frac{1}{n}\}$, we know that it is equivalent to $\{z\in D\vert 0<|f_k(z)|<\frac{1}{n}\}$ since no $f_k(z)$ takes value $0$, and so by continuities of $f_k(z)$, every $E_{k,n}$ is open. Then since $f_k(z)$ converges to $f(z)$, we have $$f^{-1}(0)=\bigcap_{l=1}^\infty\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty\bigcap_{n=m}^\infty E_{n,l}$$ Therefore we have the following question:

For each $E_{k,n}$ open, can $\bigcap_{l=1}^\infty\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty\bigcap_{n=m}^\infty E_{n,l}$ be nonempty closed nowhere dense?

If this question has a negative answer, the original one is proved since $f^{-1}(0)$ must be empty, and I think this question is also somehow interesting on its own. I feel this has something to do with the Baire Category Theorem, but I don't know how to proceed. Any help or hint would be appreciated (it would be the best if someone can answer the original problem from some other perspectives).

Answer (score 0):

Assume that there is a zero of $f(z_1, z_2... z_n)$, say $(a_1, a_2,... ,a_n)$. Fix $a_2, a_3,... ,a_n$, then we 've got a holomophic function of one variable, $f(z_1, a_2,... ,a_n)$ which must be zero for every $z_1$, by Hurwitz theorem.

Comment: So what will happen? f(z1,z2) = z1z2 at the origin is an example. However I don’t get your point.